# d3 Bilevel Partition - equal parts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm using d3 to try and use a bilevel donut chart to display data that has equal larger parts and proportional inner parts.  I'm working off the example shown here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371.

Basically, I want to show 6 groups and each will have an Open and Closed value that I want to be sized proportionally to the larger arc, but I want the large arcs all to stay 1/6 of the size of the overall donut.

I saw a similar question here with no answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195588/equal-inner-arc-angles-for-d3-bilevel-partition.

I was able to mock up the JSON to show the effect I wanted, but obviously if the data changes this is skewed.  Here is what it would look like with all equal values: [image]

Any advice?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at it a bit more, this is actually a straightforward fix.  The JSON I finally came up with looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "team1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "open",
          "size": 0.8
        },
        {
          "name": "closed",
          "size": 0.2
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
```

By making sure that the children items add to the same amount (1 in this case), I can change the chart as expected.  I did this by using percentages rather than values, so when forming my JSON, I used `size: 0.8` instead of the `size: 8` that was there previously.